# How to join the results of 2 tables side-by-side?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 queries reproducing 2 results as:

Result 1:

```
select title1,age1 from tab1 where title1 in ('1','2')
```

```
title1 age1 
1       2
2       3
```

Result 2:

```
select title2,age2 from tab2 where title2 in ('a','c')
```

```
title2 age2
a       b
c       d
```

I want my results simply joined together side-by-side as a final result:

```
title1 age1 title2 age2
1       2     a        b
2       3     c        d
```

How do I achieve this in an easy way? I searched but didn't find the solution.

== update the schema of table

```
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| title1 | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age1   | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe tab2;
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| title2 | varchar(2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| age2   | varchar(2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

=== update: 
I tried following:

```
select * from 
(select title1, age1 from tab1 order by title1,age1) as result1 , 
(select title2, age2 from tab2 order by title2,age2) as result2 ;
```

It produced 4 rows as:

```
+--------+------+--------+------+
| title1 | age1 | title2 | age2 |
+--------+------+--------+------+
|      1 |    2 | a      | b    |
|      2 |    3 | a      | b    |
|      1 |    2 | c      | d    |
|      2 |    3 | c      | d    |
+--------+------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the code for your queries.

Comment: post your table schemas. what are the relational columns, if any?

Comment: Order by without limit in a subquery has no meaning, any order is coincidental.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work good for you.

-- Example

```
select result1.title1, title1.age1,result2.title2, title2.age2 from 
  (select @i:=@i+1 AS rowId, title1, age1 from tab1,(SELECT @i:=0) a) as result1 , 
  (select @j:=@j+1 AS rowId,title2, age2 from tab2,(SELECT @j:=0) a ) as result2 
where 
  result1.rowId = result2.rowId; 
-- try this it will work perfectly fine
```

Comment: Tried this. It produced the result same as "cross join", which has 4 row at the end. I only want 2 rows.

Comment: Tried all your queries. All produces 4 rows instead of 2 rows.

Comment: you can use where clause to add condition to remove duplicate column.

Comment: i have edited the answer this will work perfectly fine for you without having a key column to join on.

Comment: just to add there is rowID and rowNum provided in Oracle but not in MYSQL so i just used a work around to do the same

Comment: Unfortunately reading & updating the same variable in a select statement in MySQL is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your SQL queries, it's hard to give you an exact answer, but you should be looking to merge them together, something like this:

```
SELECT  title_1, age_1, title_2, age_2
FROM    table1, table2
WHERE   table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: Added the query command. And your way is to join first then select. I want select first then join.

Answer (score 0):

```
select title_1, age_1 from table1
union
select title_2, age_2 from table2
```

Result is

```
title_1 age_1 title_2 age_2
1       2     
2       3    
              a        b
              c        d
```