# Quickly copying all values from one table into another – MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

Suppose I have two tables with BTREE indices that have the same number of rows but don't necessarily share data, and I want to copy the values in one column from one table into the other table. I've seen [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418158/how-to-join-the-results-of-2-tables-side-by-side) questions' [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685992/mysql-combine-query-results-side-by-side) regarding SELECTing that involve generating sequential IDs for both tables, then performing some JOIN operation based on matching these IDs together. For example (from the first answer):

```
select result1.title1, title1.age1,result2.title2, title2.age2 from 
  (select @i:=@i+1 AS rowId, title1, age1 from tab1,(SELECT @i:=0) a) as result1 , 
  (select @j:=@j+1 AS rowId,title2, age2 from tab2,(SELECT @j:=0) a ) as result2 
where 
  result1.rowId = result2.rowId; #sic.
```

However, I have two concerns:

1. I'm not sure how to update this way, since I don't know if I can make a dummy column for the destination table on the fly (i.e. something equivalent to `UPDATE (SELECT (@x:=@x+1), title1 FROM title1,(SELECT @x:=0) a ) INNER JOIN...`).
2. I am suspicious that this is in `O(n^2)` time with respect to the number of rows. This would be the case if the dummy IDs were generated first, then each run of the `JOIN` required a linear search of one or both tables. Is this the case? If so, is there a faster way to do this?

---

For example, consider the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    v INT
);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES
    (1, 3),
    (3, 4),
    (25, 7);

CREATE TABLE t2 LIKE t1;

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES
    (6, 150),
    (9, 143),
    (14, 175);
```

Suppose I wanted to replace the `v` values in `t2` with those in `t1` in one query so that `t1` becomes:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+------+
| id | v    |
+----+------+
|  1 |  150 |
|  3 |  143 |
| 25 |  175 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How would I do so?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table, and tell us which column relates a row in one table to the corresponding row in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of testing I think I've found a pretty viable solution. If you have sequential IDs on the source table, you can copy the values relatively quickly to the destination table (especially if the source table is `ENGINE=MEMORY`) using the following [admittedly somewhat unusual] query:

```
UPDATE t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @x:=0) a 
    SET t1.v=(@x:=@x+1)+(SELECT v FROM t2 WHERE id=@x)-@x;
```

The overhead from the `SELECT v...` statement is quite significant however, and it slows the query significantly.